# Numpy float64 vs Python float

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I'm battling some floating point problems in Pandas read_csv function.  In my investigation, I found this:

```
In [15]: a = 5.9975

In [16]: a
Out[16]: 5.9975

In [17]: np.float64(a)
Out[17]: 5.9974999999999996
```

Why is builtin `float` of Python and the `np.float64` type from Python giving different results?  I thought they were both C++ doubles?

Comment: Note also that the Pandas `read_csv` function employs its own super-fast string-to-float conversion that is *not* correctly rounded.  Thus after exporting a value and re-reading it, the recovered value may end up being 1 or 2 ulps different from the original.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, does this apply to `read_excel` too?

Comment: @Gathide No idea, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
>>> numpy.float64(5.9975).hex()
'0x1.7fd70a3d70a3dp+2'
>>> (5.9975).hex()
'0x1.7fd70a3d70a3dp+2'
```

They are the same number. What differs is their representation; the Python native type uses a "sane" representation, and the NumPy type uses an accurate representation.

Comment: By representation, you mean the way it is printed to screen?

Comment: Via the `__repr__()` method or its C-level equivalent, yes.

Comment: A truly *accurate* representation would actually be 5.99749999999999960920149533194489777088165283203125, which is the exact decimal value of the 64-bit float you get when you evaluate the float literal `5.9975`.

Comment: @MarkAmery The max precision a float 64 can reach is close to 10-16 (unit in the last place (ULP), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) so the idea of an exact decimal value with significantly  more than 16 digits for a floating point is misleading.

Comment: @JonathanNappee: Every numeric binary64 representation does in fact have an exact decimal equivalent. The trouble occurs when we believe that a much less precise decimal value is represented by a given binary64 value.

Comment: This answer leaves a lot ambiguous about the types, but anyway in python 3 they actually deliver the same string representation and are (almost universally a facade over the [same underlying C type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569450/1509695))