# TypeError: len() of unsized object when slicing a dataframe - different float formats?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to slice a dataframe based on some previously defined conditions defined in a separate array. When looping through that array to find the relevant slices of the dataframe, I run into a problem. The first iteration works fine, but the loop breaks during the second iteration, throwing `TypeError: len() of unsized object`.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
    std     sterr   Z       smooth
0   5.1     2.28    0       7.640484
1   5.13    2.29    0.1     7.532409
2   5.15    2.3     0.21    7.406423
3   5.17    2.31    0.31    7.267842
4   5.19    2.32    0.42    7.121988
5   5.21    2.33    0.52    6.974179
6   5.23    2.34    0.62    6.829734
7   5.25    2.35    0.73    6.693973
8   5.27    2.36    0.83    6.584009
9   5.29    2.37    0.94    6.49429
10  5.31    2.38    1.04    6.427032
```

Here is the code of the loop:

```
turnz = df.ix[np.array(turn_iloc), 'Z']
c = 0.
print "turn points", np.array(turnz)
for i, zi in enumerate(np.array(turnz)):
    z0 = c
    print z0, zi, type(z0), type(zi)
    x = df.loc[((z0<=df['Z'])& (df['Z']<=zi)), 'Z']
    y = df.loc[((z0<=df['Z'])& (df['Z']<=zi)), 'smooth']
    print len(x), len(y)
    print type(x), type(y)
    c = zi
```

And these are the printed outputs:

```
turn points [ 1.04  2.19  2.5   4.06]
0.0 1.04 <type 'float'> <type 'numpy.float64'>
11 11
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1.04 2.19 <type 'numpy.float64'> <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

after this, it throws the error.
However, if I try to slice the dataframe using these printed values outside the loop, it works fine.

```
print "IS IT",df.loc[((1.04<=df['Z'])& (df['Z']<=2.19)), 'Z']
```

prints

```
IS IT 10    1.04
11    1.14
12    1.25
13    1.35
14    1.46
15    1.56
16    1.67
17    1.77
18    1.87
19    1.98
20    2.08
21    2.19
Name: Z, dtype: float64
```

What am I missing?

The complete traceback is below, if it helps:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b6d427f5dae7> in <module>()
      9     z0 = c
     10     print z0, zi, type(z0), type(zi)
---> 11     x = df.loc[((z0<=df['Z'])& (df['Z']<=zi)), 'Z']
     12     y = df.loc[((z0<=df['Z'])& (df['Z']<=zi)), 'smooth']
     13     print len(x), len(y)

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    739             return NotImplemented
    740         elif isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, pd.Index)):
--> 741             if len(self) != len(other):
    742                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
    743             return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other)),

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

**OUTCOME**

it turns out my dataframe has troubles slicing with numpy floats. converting `z0` and `zi` to `float` solves the problem!

Comment: `ix` is deprecated... try `loc` instead?

Comment: `loc` works only for keys, `iloc` only for indices. How else than using `ix` can I combine the two? Moreover, why does it work in the first iteration, if this was the problem? (and I tried it and it did not solve the problem)

Comment: No, `loc` works with boolean masks too. `iloc` doesn't.

Comment: Ok, good point. But still, as I said. If this was the problem, it would break already during the first iteration and, moreover, doing that did not make any difference.

Comment: I see. Is this all your code? It appears that one of your variables are not what you think they are.

Comment: It does indeed. But which one? It seems to me I have printed all I could and it shows correctly...

Comment: I just tested your code and it executed without error.  The only modifications I made were: `turnz=[ 1.04, 2.19, 2.5, 4.06]; cislo=1.04` and wrapped `print` statements for Python 3 compatibility.  Using Pandas 0.20.3 and Python 3.6.  I did get the warning about `.ix` being deprecated, but no errors.  If you define `turnz` statically as I did, without extracting its value from `df`, do you still get the error?

Comment: I see, sorry, should have specified, I am on Python 2.7.12 and pandas 0.18.1

Comment: regarding the static definition of turnz, it looks good, but this way it is only applicable to this particular example...

Comment: But thank you @andrew_reece - this brought me to an idea of the format of a float. Currently, the values of turnz are `<type 'numpy.float64'>`. When I converted them to `float`, it works!

Comment: I mean that only as a debugging step.  I just tested on 2.7.12 and Pandas 0.18.1, and also ran without error, given `turnz` is statically defined.  That suggests the problem is with `turnz`.

Comment: @durbachit, good!  Consider writing your own answer and accepting it.  Even better if you can figure out why the `float64` caused the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this problem lies in the printout of the first iteration:

`0.0 1.04 <type 'float'> <type 'numpy.float64'>`

the first iteration has `float` as an input and it works. The remaining values, however, are elements of a numpy array and are formatted as numpy floats. This is what the dataframe does not accept.

```
z0 = float(z0)
zi = float(zi)
```

does the trick.

Now, the question is... why?
If we print `turnz.dtype` and `df['Z']` dtype, both are `float64`, so they seem to be the same. But python treats them differently, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27098653/5553319)

Comment: Really? That's pretty silly if pandas doesn't let you do that.

Comment: Totally agree! Perhaps something that the developers could look into in future versions of pandas?