# Why does Pandas.DataFrame.iloc convert to numpy.float64 and round?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Take this number as an example:

```
1.64847910404205
```

If I create a Pandas DataFrame with a row and this value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 77, 'data': 1.64847910404205}])
```

and then iterate over the rows (Okay... the 'row') and inspect:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index > 0:
        previous_row = df.iloc[index]
```

Of course the above is weird: why would I iterate over the rows just to pull the same row from the DF? Forget that; I removed the `-1` to illustrate.

Now, if I use `SciView` (part of `IntelliJ`) and the `data` tab to inspect the rows individually, I get this:

```
row
data: 1.64847910404205

previous_row
data: 1.64847910404
```

Notice that `previous_row` has been rounded. It's because they are for some reason different data types...

```
row: 
type(row) #float64

previous_row:
type(previous_row) #numpy.float64
```

I'm curious to know: why does `iloc` convert to a `numpy.float64` and how can I prevent it from doing so?

I need the same level of precision as I will later be doing Peak Signal to Noise Ratio (PSNR) calculations. Of course, I could just convert the `float` to a `numpy.float64`, but I don't want to lose precision.

Comment: It might just be the way it's displayed. What does `row == previous_row` return?

Comment: @busybear Oh, good call. It does show as being equal. Why would they display differently?The data types are different: is it just the `labels` which are different, while the actual `data` is the same?

Comment: Python doesn't have a `float64` builtin object (just `float`), so I don't think they are actually different data types. Perhaps `numpy.float64` was imported as `float64` somewhere. Just speculating.

Comment: Related: [Numpy float64 vs Python float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098529/numpy-float64-vs-python-float)

Answer (score 2):

The type of the `'data'` column in your dataframe is `numpy.float64`, even if Pandas only reports it as `float64`. You can prove this to yourself with the following:

```
df['data'].dtype.type is numpy.float64
```

which will return `True`. An alternative form would be:

```
type(df['data'].values[0]) is numpy.float64
```

which will also return `True`.

Any difference in display is down to how `SciView` is interpreting your code.