# astype('float') changes data, not just data type

Tags: python, pandas

I download a bunch of csv-files from an aws s3-bucket and put them in a dataframe. Before uploading the dataframe to sql server I would like to change the columns of the dataframe to have the right datatypes.

When I run `astype('float64')` on a column I want to change it not only changes the datatype but also the data.

Code:

```
df['testcol'] = df['lineId'].astype('float64')
```

[pycharm image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccF20.png)

I attached a picture to visualize the error. As you can see the data in the third column (`testcol`) is different to the data in the second column (`lineId`) even though only the datatype should be changed.

A `pl_id` can have multiple `lineId`'s, that's why I added and sorted by `pl_id` in the picture.

Am I using `astype()` wrong or is this a pandas bug?

Comment: Have you tried using pd.to_numeric(df['lineId'])? That might cast the data type without truncating your id.

Comment: Did you try "float" instead of "float64"?

Comment: Yes, I tried 'float' and pd.to_numeric(). Same problem.

Comment: Couldn't edit my question so here is the update:RunTheGauntlet was right, it's a problem with the data size. Since my endgoal was int anyway it was enough to use `astype(numpy.int64).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it seems that the float64 is not sufficient to carry that long integer:

```
np.float64('211052094743748628')
Out[135]: 2.1105209474374864e+17
```

"The max precision a float 64 can reach is close to 10-16 (unit in the last place (ULP), see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) so the idea of an exact decimal value with significantly more than 16 digits for a floating point is misleading."
[Numpy float64 vs Python float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098529/numpy-float64-vs-python-float)

Consider maybe using int64, which can be more suitable for the size of Id in your dataset:

```
np.int64('211052094743748628')
Out[150]: 211052094743748628
```

Comment: `int`, more specifically, `Int64` is the datatype I am actually trying to assign to this column, but [this pandas bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25472) says I need to first convert the column to `float`. Any other datatype I could use?

Comment: I just tried `df['testcol5']=df['lineId'].apply(int)` but the problem persists.

Comment: How about astype('int64') ?

Comment: That doesn't fail, but it produces the same wrong output `float64` does.