# Rounding to no decimal returns one decimal .0 in Python

Tags: python, rounding

According to tooltip (at least in Spyder) for function `round`, if second argument is omitted or `None`the returned result is an integer. However:

```
round(np.pi)
Out[214]: 3

round(np.sqrt(2))
Out[215]: 1.0
```

In the first case it's an integer but in the second it's not and also wrong if interpreted as a float with one digit; the natural way to interpret a number looking like that if one doesn't know the details behind the code presenting it.

I don't see the logic behind using an additional .0 when presenting a number supposedly rounded to an integer.

Comment: can't reproduce, both return type int here.

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11810

Comment: what version of _numpy_ are you using (what is the output of `np.__version__`)?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I'm using numpy 1.20.3

Comment: I'm running Python 3.9.7 and numpy 1.21.1 and the output from both *round()* calls returns **<class 'int'>**. Having said that, I can't see why the version of numpy might be relevant unless you're using its *round()* function in which case the return types would be **<class 'numpy.float64'>**

Comment: @DarkKnight It might actually be relevant. The built-in `round` function may rely on the numpy specific `__round__` function

Comment: The difference is occuring due to representation in numpy this is a similar issue [numpy-float64-vs-python-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098529/numpy-float64-vs-python-float)

Comment: @DarkKnight: The version of NumPy is relevant because when Python's `round` function is called for a NumPy `float64` value, the actual rounding computation is delegated to the `float64.__round__` method. The implementation of that method was changed in NumPy 1.19.0 to be consistent with `float.__round__`. See https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.19.0-notes.html#change-output-of-round-on-scalars-to-be-consistent-with-python

Comment: The issue is compounded by the fact that numpy.sqrt() returns a numpy.float64 type whereas numpy.pi is a traditional Python float

Comment: @DarkKnight: Yep, good point.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I was running Numpy 1.17 and now I'm on 1.19.5 and rounding is consistent.