# Difference between pandas <NA> and NaN for numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, null, na

I have a data frame column as float64 full of `NaN` values, If I cast it again to float64 they got substituted for `<NA>` values which are not the same.

I know that the `<NA>` values are `pd.NA`, while `NaN` values are `np.nan` , so they are different things. So why casting an already float64 column to float64 changed `NaN` to `<Na>` ?

Here's an example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.0,2.0]})
print(df.dtypes)
#output is: float64

df['a'] = np.nan
print(df.dtypes)
# output is float64

print(df)
    a
0   NaN
1   NaN

#Now, lets cast that float64 to float 64
df3['a']=df3['a'].astype(pd.Float64DType())
print(df3.dtypes)
#output is Float64, notice it's uppercase F this time, previously it was lowercase

print(df3)

    a
0   <NA>
1   <NA>
```

it seems `float64` and `Float64` are two different things. And `NaN` (np.nan) is the null value for `float64` while `<NA>` (pd.NA) is the null for `Float64`

Is this correct? And if so, what's under the hoods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. **float64** and **Float64** are two different data types in pandas. The difference is that **Float64** is an extension type that can hold missing values using a special  sentinel, while **float64** is a native numpy type that uses **NaN** to represent missing values. Under the hood, **Float64** uses a numpy array with dtype **object** to store the values, while **float64** uses a numpy array with dtype **float64**.
This means that **Float64** may have some performance overhead compared to **float64**, but it also allows more consistent handling of missing values across different data types.

Check this out: [Numpy float64 vs Python float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098529/numpy-float64-vs-python-float)

Comment: I don't think that last link is relevant.